# gcc optimizations while copying an array

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction, assembly

I need to profile an application which performs a lot of array copies, so I ended up profiling this very simple function:

```
typedef unsigned char UChar;
void copy_mem(UChar *src, UChar *dst, unsigned int len) {
        UChar *end = src + len;
        while (src < end)
                *dst++ = *src++;
}
```

I'm using Intel VTune to do the actual profiling, and from there I've seen that there are dramatic differences when compiling with gcc -O3 and "plain" gcc (4.4).

To understand the why and how, I've got the assembly output of both compilation.

The unoptimized version is this one:

```
.L3:
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        movzbl  (%eax), %edx
        movl    12(%ebp), %eax
        movb    %dl, (%eax)
        addl    $1, 12(%ebp)
        addl    $1, 8(%ebp)
.L2:
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        cmpl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        jb      .L3
        leave
```

So I see that it first load a dword from *src and puts the lower byte into edx, then it stores it into *dst and updates the pointers: simple enough.

Then I saw the optimized version, and I didn't understand nothing.

**EDIT**: [here](https://gist.github.com/raw/961601/b690375a574f99e501bd83029ba8cf0526075cec/gistfile1.txt) there is the optimized assembly.

My question therefore is: what kind of optimizations gcc can do in this function?

Comment: Use memcpy - it should be way faster than your loop.

Comment: Please copy the optimized output to your question.

Comment: I cannot use memcpy, because I can have overlaps.

Comment: @akappa: Then use `memmove`. It can handle overlaps.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict

Comment: @KennyTM: thanks, but I'd like to understand anyway how the compiler can optimize away the whole thing

Comment: @aka be aware that if you have overlaps, restrict may cause problems

Comment: @Anycorn: I think I'll use memmove, but it is an interesting keyword anyway :)

Comment: @Paul R: technically, GCC should recognize this loop and optimize it as it would do for `memcpy`, this is what MSVC does (thoigh now they use SSE branching for mem ops...).

Comment: @Necrolis: true, but in the interest of portability it's best not to make any assumptions about what optimisations a given compiler will or will not perform

Comment: @Paul R: yeah, thats one problem with relying on specific optimizations over using intrinsics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That optimized code is quite a mess, but I can spot 3 loops (near L6, L13 and L12). I think gcc does what @GJ suggested (I upvoted him). The loop near L6 moves 4 bytes every time, while loop #2 moves only one byte and is executed only sometimes after loop #1. I still can't get loop #3 since it's identical to loop #2.

Comment: yes, I think it is the only true optimization it can do with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Your unoptimized function moving byte per byte!**

If you first calcolate the length, than you can move 4 byte at once, the rest 1..3 bytes move manualy. If you can ensure proper (4 byte) memory aligment the copy function should be also faster.
And there is no need for incrementing pointers on the stack, you can use registers.
All this thinks will dramatically improve the speed of function.

Or use dedicated mem move functions like memmove!

Answer (score 1):

Well the types of optimizations depend on the function and its properties, if the function was marked as inline, and was small enough, it would be turned into and unrolled loop of `MOV`, which is faster that `REP` based variants (and it can avoid register spilling). for unknown sizes you get the `REP MOVS` family of instructions (starting with the largest word size to lessen the amount of loops for a constant size, else it'll use the size of the data unit your copying).

If SSE is enable, it would more than likely use either unrolled unaligned moves (`MOVDQU`) where the length permits or looped unaligned moves (dunno if it would use temporal prefetching, the gain from that depends on the block size) if the length is great enough. if the source/dest are aligned correctly it'll try use the faster aligned variants.

As it stands right now, that best you can get on that func is `MOVSB` when its not inlined.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest x86 assembly instructions gcc can generate would be `rep movsd`, which would copy 4 bytes at a time. The standard libc function `memcpy` in `<string.h>`, together with the special inlining gcc does for `memcpy` and many other functions in `<string.h>` give you the fastest possible result.

Comment: so it is just an application of loop unrolling (unrolling 4 copies per time)?

Comment: wouldnt movpd/movps be faster?

Comment: @akappa: `rep movsd' does loop unrolling, but it also contains the loop itself, i.e. it's one compound assembly instruction for copying a large data block. It should be a bit faster than a loop containing move, compare and jump instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You would also benefit from using [restrict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) here.